# Favourite tags length

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching, feed

I know that I can see all questions with my favourite tags here:

https://stackexchange.com/filters/262360/favorite-tags

But... this list is limited to 100 questions only. Is there a way to see all questions with my favourite tags that has not been listed before?

The reason is that I have a lot of tags, and I want to see all questions with these tags one time a day, and it is very possible that in one day there are more than 100 questions.

Now I can see the ALL question list using a program that reads and save all RSS elements, but I don't know how to do this on "Favourite tags" page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see a full list of posts with yours favorite tags by searching with [`intags:mine`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=intags%3Amine) option as described in the advanced search [help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching):

> `intags:mine` returns only posts that appear in tags you have marked as favorite. (If you don't have any tags, this operator does nothing. For better results, update your preferences.)

Comment: Ok, i put in search box "intags:mine is:q", but i can't differentiate what questions i have listed before and what questions i haven't listed before, no?

Comment: @Dani If I undestand you correctly, use can change sort order by selecting `newest`, `votes`, `active` tabs.

Comment: Yes, but with this form there isn't a way for signalize what questions i have listed before and what questions are news. For example, i search "intags:mine is:q" by "newest" and result is A,B,C,D. After, i search other time with same parameters and result is X,Y,Z,A,B,C,D. You cant know that X,Y,Z are new, no?

Comment: @Dani You can also use filtering by dates. See full help (link in the answer) for more info.